# Why databricks $t and $v is reffered once cosmos table api is connected

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

Cosmos table api is connected through databricks.

```
Endpoint = "https://acccuntanme.documents.azure.com:443/"
MasterKey = "keyyyyy"

Cfg1 = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": Endpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey": MasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database": "TablesDB",
  "spark.cosmos.container": "Deals_Metainfo",
  "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled" : "true"
}

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**Cfg1) \
  .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled", "true").load()
print(df.count())
```

Results were as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px0Kz.png)

One more question here is ,

created another data frame from above results.

```
df2= df.select("CreationDate.$v","$pk","filename.$v","Sno.$v","Status.$v") \
 .toDF("CreationDate","PrimaryKey","Filename","Sno","Status")
```

results as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1ha.png)

Created temp view from top that.

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("v_filenames_data")
```

So if i try to query view for status results is not appering.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXDE7.png)

created temp view

Comment: try with this query `spark.sql("Select * from v_filenames_data where Status = 'Open'").show()`

Comment: @PratikLad-MT No luck  i checked those cases.. Can we save the data as it is from cosmos table api?

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Aside from that: You're consuming a Table API instance as if it were a core (SQL) API instance, which is why you're seeing the internal table representation properties. There's no direct way to consume Azure Table Storage (or Cosmos DB's Table API), so it's not like you're doing anything wrong. And you've already figured out how to map those "value" properties into named columns in your dataframe.